# Incluir informacion que este fuera de datatables en jquery buttons

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando exporto excel me funciona perfecto para la tabla, pero no me sirve de nada si el archivo no incluye información de a quien va dirigido ese archivo, habra alguna forma de incluir la informacion que se encuentra fuera de la tabla?

estoy utilizando:

```
i$('#tabla_detalle').DataTable({
       dom: 'Bfrtip',
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        buttons: [{
        extend: 'csv',
        className: 'btn btn-success',
        title: 'Archivo de ingreso',
        text: "Exportar a excel"
        }]
    });
```